# CSS background image without text?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a simple info icon and I want to display it as css background image. This is what I tried:

```
span.info {
    background-image: url(info.png);
    float: right;
    width: 17px;
    display: block;
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
<span class="info"></span>
```

This does not display the image. I have to have some text, like this:

```
<span class="info">test</span>
```

This displays the image with text, but I want it without any text, just the image. Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Totally irrelevant to your question, but as you’ve got `float:right` in there, you don’t need `display:block`. Floated elements are automatically treated as block-level elements, even if you apply `display:inline` to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set a height in your style.

```
span.info {
    background-image: url(info.png);
    float: right;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ok, good, that always shows the image. The image is bigger that the 17px, is there a way to scale it?

Comment: @user1540714: if the image is taller than 17px, set the height of the `<span>` to the height of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Even with `display:block` (which is mandatory) you need to specify the height of your span.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image only why dont you use `<img>` directly. It will give you more control over the image.

But you can have the background image of span as follows.

`<span>` is  not a block element like `<div>`. So you have to set its `"display: block"`. Then specify some height and width for the span.

Answer (score 1):

Without content the span will not show anything, unless you specify a height (and width) in the CSS...

```
span.info {
    height: 17px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:
`<span class="info">&nbsp;</span>`